# One repository/multiple projects without getting mixed up?

Tags: mercurial, repository, organization

After reading Joel's last article on Mercurial, I'm giving it a shot on XP as a single-user, single-computer source control system.

One thing I'd like to check, though, is: It'd be easier to just create a repository of all the tiny projects I keep in eg. C:\VB.Net\, but the result is that the changes I make to the different projects therein (C:\VB.Net\ProjectA\, C:\VB.Net\ProjectB\, etc.) will be mixed in a single changelog.

But if I use a single repository for all projects, when I do diff's or go through the change history, will I be able to filter data so that I only see changes pertaining to a given project? Otherwise, is creating repositories in each project directory the only solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I'd keep one repository for each single project. The overhead is minimal (just one `hg init` for each source code directory, or one right-click in Explorer), and you won't get confused. After all, why should a change to one program affect the version history of a completely unrelated one?

Of course, you *can* see the history of each file in the Repository Explorer, but I think it goes against the very concept of version control to mix unrelated stuff into one repository.

Comment: Thanks guys. So I'll just go ahead and create a repo in each project sub-dir.

Answer (score 4):

The right granularity for a DVCS (i.e. a repo where *all* the history can be cloned) is the project.

If you have several projects which have different development lifecycle (i.e. a change in one does not always affect the other), they should be in their own repo.

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody uses bitbucket, they allow a only one *private* repository, so you can put all your projects in there if you want them to be private. I would like to hear comments about this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If you do go with one repository, and only have shallow projects:

```
cd C:\VB.Net\ProjectA\
hg log *.*
```

Otherwise, may have to specify specific file extensions to avoid too much recursion:

```
cd C:\VB.Net\ProjectA\
hg log **/*.cpp
```

It can be a little slow though...  And tags/branches might get confusing if the projects really are separate.

Note: I hardly think "Hello world!" deserves its own repository just because it may be "stand alone".