# managing large numbers of mercurial repositories on a server

Tags: mercurial, multiple-repositories

I've read about the single central repository vs. multiple repositories approach in Mercurial (e.g. [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077439/mercurial-granular-repositories-vs-large-repositories-and-shared-third-party-t) [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475520/one-repository-multiple-projects-without-getting-mixed-up) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748552/how-to-best-configure-a-central-repository-multiple-central-repositories-for-mer)), and it's pretty clear that small repositories (one per self-contained project) is the right approach.

But this implies a large number of repositories, where by "large number" I mean enough that it's hard to keep track of which contains what. I'm in a small team (< 7 developers) and with the number of projects we work on, different branches/versions, etc., I can see us having 50 or 60 repositories.

Are there any tools out there to help catalog/manage a Mercurial server with dozens or hundreds of repositories?

---

edit: I'm using both [SCM-Manager](https://bitbucket.org/sdorra/scm-manager/wiki/Home) (within our firewall) and [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) (outside our firewall). Oh, and of course each developer is going to have his/her own local clones of a bunch of them.

The problem is not *how* to put large numbers of mercurial repositories on a server, but how to keep track of them all.

Comment: The description of the repo should be enough to keep track of the ones on the server and it's up to each developer to keep track of their own repositories.

Comment: With all due respect, you discount the effect of human error.

Answer (score 0):

How are you serving these repositories?  If you use `hgweb` then the simplest way is to add descriptions to your `hgrc` files on the server.  You do this in the `[web]` section like this:

```
[web]
description=Description goes here
```

This adds the descriptions to the web based interface which is fine for us (we have about 30 repositories)

Other than that, I think that most of the options that you have involve choosing a web based publishing method that includes this functionality such as Rhodecode.  Other publishing methods are available [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories#Choosing_a_publishing_method).

Answer (score 0):

As @Steve suggested, the web approach is very good. I manage 50+ repositories this way.

I have a process running the `hg serve` in a batch file:

`hg serve --prefix mercurial --address my-hg-server --port 8000 --web-conf hg-web.conf --accesslog hg-access.log --errorlog hg-error.log`

The **hg-web.conf** looks like this:

```
[web]
style = default
allow_push = *
push_ssl = false

[paths]
repos1 = \\hg-repos-server\repos1
repos2 = \\hg-repos-server\repos2
....
```

then, by accessing:

> http : // my-hg-server:8000/mercurial

I get a page with links to all my repositories. A link can be copied and cloned by the user.

This is a very simple setup and works great for us.

You can wrap the hg serve batch file or shell script to be run as a service and you can put this all behind an Apache web server to manage more security.

I hope this helps